# Render process include what in camera or whole scene?

Tags: rendering, camera, scene

imagine you have very complex scene and camera point to a part of it !
of course render give you what in the camera view ; the thing that i don't know is
should i delete extera meshes for faster render process or it dosen't affect ?
thanks for your basic assist :)

Comment: Depends if the materials reflect the meshes outside the camera view. Or if they animate and need to be calculated. But overall Blender is very good at only rendering/calculating things that need to be. If you have the memory to store all the optimisations.